# Login to application with instagram?

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I am try login to application with Instagram, I am using from this [LINK](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/instagram-integration-android-application-tutorial) but I can login just with my account Instagram and I can't login with others accounts .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should invite them and they accept you invite!

**just you can add 3 people to your application.**

follow this link to see more details : 
https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Answer (score 1):

Probably your app in sandbox mode

> Since this mode is meant for development, apps in Sandbox mode are not visible to the general public, but instead are only visible to a limited set of up to 10 authorized 'sandbox users'

for more details please visit https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/